# Reverse Inlines in Django Admin for Many to Many

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Apologies if this has been asked before and my searches have not uncovered the solution.    I'm looking to include admin inlines for two models.  Django version is 4.1.4

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author_series = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    series = models.ManyToManyField(Series)
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + " (" + str(self.pk) + ")"

class Series(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.publisher + " " + self.name
```

I'm able to complete the forward relationship successfully using Model.field.through format:

```
class SeriesInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book.series.through
    
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [SeriesInline,]
```

but would like the reverse as well.

```
class InlineSeriesBooks(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book.series_set.through
    ... Remainder is commented out ...

class SeriesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'category', 'publisher', 'link', 'created', 'modified']
    fields = ['name', 'category', 'publisher', 'link', 'created', 'modified']
    readonly_fields = ["created", "modified"]
    inlines = [InlineSeriesBooks,]
```

All the links seem to be suggesting the former through solution such as [Django Admin, accessing reverse many to many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48372252/django-admin-accessing-reverse-many-to-many) but with the spelling correct gets stuck in a loop.  If I remove the inlines statement the page will load.

I have confirmed that I can follow the relationship on both directions in the front end with:

```
{% for series in book.series.all %}..
```

and

```
{% for book in series.book_set.all %}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not "though", it's "through". Also, on the book model, the accessor is "series", so the last point should be `Book.series.through`. Can you try those options again and let us know if they work.

Comment: Hi @vinkomlacic, thanks for pointing out the spelling error.  I've updated the error and problem description.

Answer (score 0):

This is just equivalent, since both refer to a "hidden" model, so:

```
class BookSeriesInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book.series.through
    

class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [BookSeriesInline,]
    

class SeriesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [BookSeriesInline,]
```

You thus can use the same inline, which is a junction table between the two models, for both admins.

Comment: Sadly, this is the same as above.   Page doesn't load.   Remove the inline statement and it loads.

Comment: @ByteInsight: did you specify anything else in the `TabularInline`, `ModelAdmin` or models (like `__str__`), that might result in an infinite loop?

Comment: Sorry, out internet went out, just come back.   I don't believe so.   I have updated the admin and model defs.   It is possible that a migration has messed up?   I have ran makemigrations and migrate.  I don't have anything outstanding.   But this use to be a 1 to many relationship.   1 Series had many books.